# Gmail API returning more data than expected

Tags: gmail-api

We are making the following query programmatically to Gmail API for our business gmail account having many users:

```
in:anywhere newer_than:1d
```

it should return us messages sent or received within the last one day, however we are getting all messages that we have sent or received since we created our organization account few years ago. We then tried making this query:

```
in:anywhere after:2015/08/20 before:2015/08/21
```

this also gives us emails for last few years. Executing these queries on the gmail web search bar show just a handful of email which is correct.

Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior with the APIs? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Could you post the actual code/snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I tried with [threads.list via the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.threads.list?userId=me&maxResults=1000&q=in%253Aanywhere%20newer_than%253A1d&_h=10&) and it seems to work fine. That might be a reasonable workaround depending on your use case.

But with messages.list I'm getting weird behavior too and there may be a bug. Using newer_than with values up to 7h works OK, but once I get to 8h it starts returning everything. Using [before/after](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.messages.list?userId=me&q=in%253Aanywhere%20after%253A2015%252F08%252F20%20before%253A2015%252F08%252F21&_h=31&) seems to work fine for me too (though I did accidentally reverse the dates in which case it returns everything...)

UPDATE: Actually, it does seem to be working correctly for me. The one thing that is off is the resultSizeEstimate. The estimate is wildly wrong, but the actual number of items returns after retrieving successive pages is fine.